# Type error: Duplicate identifier 'pageProps'

Tags: typescript

The Error:

```
Type error: Duplicate identifier 'pageProps'.
```

My _app.tsx

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import '../styles/globals.css';



export default function App({Component}: {Component:any} , pageProps: { session: any,  ...pageProps: any[]}) {
}) {
  return (
    // `session` comes from `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps`.
    // Avoids flickering/session loading on first load.
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

global.d.ts

```
// global.d.ts
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
// bunch of globals and yeah. 
declare global {
    var mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
    var prisma: PrismaClient;
}
```

types.d.ts

```
import type { DefaultUser } from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user?: DefaultUser & {
      id: string;
    };
  }
}
```

next-env.d.ts

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />

// NOTE: This file should not be edited
// see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript for more information.
```

I don't know why i keep getting that error

My pkg.json

```
{
  "name": "basically-email",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.2",
    "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter": "^1.0.1",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.9.2",
    "@types/next-auth": "^3.15.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.4.0",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "prisma": "^3.9.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

I tried going through some other q's But I still Im confused about the .d.ts Files If you guys have any ideas on how to Fix this error Please Let me know, thanks! I encountered this error while i was deploying the app the vercel, the build failed and I had to check the logs but when i run the proj on localhost:3000 it works without any problems again i still don't get why vercel showed up this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You literally have two `pageProps`. This is a really bad question to ask on stack overflow, very low effort.

[image]